# difference between return (function()) and return true in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following sample document

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>My home page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My home page</h1>
    <p>Hello, I am Marijn and this is my home page.</p>
    <p>I also wrote a book! Read it
    <a href="http://eloquentjavascript.net">here</a>.</p>
  </body> 
</html>
```

i wrote a recursive function  to find out whether a string is in document or not

```
function talksAbout(node, string) {


 if(node.nodeType == document.ELEMENT_NODE){
      for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;i++){
       if(talksAbout(node.childNodes[i],string))
         return true;
      }
     return false;
   }
  else if(node.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE){
     return (node.nodeValue.indexOf(string) > -1);
  }
}

console.log(talksAbout(document.body,"wrote"));
```

but when i change if statement in 3rd line from

```
if(talksAbout(node.childNodes[i],string))
   return true;
```

to simple

```
return taksAbout(node.childNodes[i],string)
```

it shows wrong answer.can somebody find the difference between two.

Comment: i think i got this. doing it the other way  causes function to examine only one path of the tree. from root to first child then it's first child and so on.

Comment: return is not a function its statement to return any thing from the function.

Comment: You are evaluation `return (expression) `and not `return (function())`. In your case a conditional expression, the result of which would be a true/false value; if you did `return function.call()` it would result in a *truthy* or *falsy* value

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
if(talksAbout(node.childNodes[i],string))
   return true;
```

checks the return of the call and returns true IF the result is true.  Doing it this way:

```
return taksAbout(node.childNodes[i],string)
```

Returns on the first item of the iteration, without checking the rest. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple flow logic error:

There is a difference in the following two blocks of pseudocode:

```
 foreach item in list
     if (f(item))
        return true;
```

And

```
 foreach item in list
     return f(item)
```

The first block will return `true` if any item creates a true result.

The second block will simply return `true` or `false` depending on the result of the first item.

Your change essentially converted your code block from the first example to the second example.

Answer (score 0):

the function `talksAbout` doesn't return a boolean value in all cases:

```
...
else if(node.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE){
    return (node.nodeValue.indexOf(string) > -1);
}
...
```

If this condition meets will return a positive integer or -1:

[IndexOf docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Also if this condition doen't meets will return null. When you do check and return `true` your are assuring that the return value is a `boolean` if your return (function()) you are returning the return value of the function and as I explained above it could be a `boolean` an `integer` or null in your function.

If you want assure you're returning a `boolean` just return if in all cases in your function.

Hope it helps!